# XSL for-each with the value of the attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

First, here is a part of my XML :

```
<BASE>
    <project client="Disney" num="DN001" type="film">
        <title>Moana</title>
    </project>
    <project client="Disney" num="DN002" type="trailer">
        <title>The BFG</title>
    </project>
    <project client="Warner" num="WN001" type="film">
        <title>Batman</title>
    </project>
</BASE>
```

With XSL, I want to show all projects according to the value of the attribute "client". I would like to do this with just one for-each, considering that in my DTD the attribute is set like this :

```
<!ATTLIST project 
    client (Disney|Warner|Universal) #REQUIRED
    num CDATA #REQUIRED
    type (film|trailer) #REQUIRED>
```

For example (I know the @*client part is wrong):

```
<xsl:for-each select="./project/@*client">
<xsl:value-of select="count(//../project/@*client)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here, I want to show how many Disney projects I have, then how many Warner projects, etc.

Thank you !!

Comment: Can you show the output you expect in this case. Can you also say if you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, as this looks like a grouping issue, and the answer will differ depending on what version of XSLT you are using. Thanks!

Comment: Hi ! I have no idea which version I am using :/ I am just creating a .xsl file on TextWrangler if that can help.

The output would be :
2
1

So first we will see the amount of Disney projects and then the amount of Warner projects

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `for-each`, and a `key` really seems to make the most sense.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="client-key" match="project" use="@client" />
    <xsl:template match="/">   
        <xsl:variable name="disneyCount" select="count(key('client-key', 'Disney'))" />
        <xsl:variable name="warnerCount" select="count(key('client-key', 'Warner'))" />
        <xsl:variable name="universalCount" select="count(key('client-key', 'Universal'))" />

        <xsl:if test="$disneyCount &gt; 0">
            Disney: <xsl:value-of select="$disneyCount" />
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$warnerCount &gt; 0">
            Warner: <xsl:value-of select="$warnerCount" />
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$universalCount &gt; 0">
            Universal: <xsl:value-of select="$universalCount" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This will work with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvZ

I'm operating under the assumption here that you're not concerned about non-conforming data (people not following your DTD), and that you're not necessarily concerned about the order in the document.  If either isn't the case, you could use Muenchian grouping like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="client-key" match="project" use="@client" />
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:for-each select="//project[count(. | key('client-key', @client)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="@client" />: <xsl:value-of select="count(key('client-key', @client))" />;        
        </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6rewNz2